# how to phpunit a factory class

Tags: php, phpunit

First of all I'm starting with unit testing and I have no idea how to test a factory class. I've done the basic assertions but now I've started digging in a real app and I'm facing problems to figure out what to test. Could someone give me a direction how to test this class? Thanks.

```
class NameFactory
{
    public function newInstance()
    {
        return new Name();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the answer below is good for your shown use case, however it seems very odd to me to have to instantiate a `NameFactory` object in order to then instantiate a `Name` object.  Have you considered making this a static method?

Comment: To answer your noted issue of "I'm facing problems to figure out what to test"...  Typically you want to write a set of tests that can exercise every line of code in a method (in most cases you need multiple tests to do this unlike this simple case shown here).  You should test edge cases like bad/unexpected/incomplete input in addition to your happy path test cases.  You are striving for 100% of all lines being covered (executed) via your collection of tests (though not always possible).

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the factory class or factory method will just create a object for you and return it. Sometimes, in factory methods in particular, you might have switch or if/else logic to return different objects depending on the outcome of that logic.

The method you just posted, does not lend itself for testing in my opinion, it is to simplistic. However, if you wanted to test it, you could:

```
class NameFactoryTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testNewInstance() {
        $nameFactory = new NameFactory();
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Name', $nameFactory->newInstance());
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer here and probably the only unit test you would need based on the simplicity of the method.  Your test in this case would cover 100% of lines in this method and all logic branches (there are none).

Comment: Thank you Mike, and what you wrote is true ofcourse, it is 100% coverage indeed.